# Is it possible to install a .NET application on Windows Sandbox?

Tags: .net, windows, .net-runtime, windows-sandbox

I'm using Windows Sandbox currently and it looks like there's no way to run a .NET application. Although the Sandbox has .NET 4.8 installed, when I try to run a downloaded .NET desktop application it complains that the runtime is not available.

[image]

Trying to install a specific runtime (4.7.2 is what the download takes me to) gives the error above.

So is there some way to run .NET applications on the Sandbox?

Comment: I have the same problem.did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

it's a bug introduced with KB4495620 and (again) KB4502584.
See also [this page on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/bq90ov/net_framework_not_working_in_windows_sandbox/).

Comment: the same issue for kb4506991, avoid to install it or remove it if you want to use .NET into Sandbox.